# Email Validation for College Email Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email-validation

I want to make an email validation that only accept emails from my college so I wanted to know how to do that.

```
    email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

validates :email, :presence => true,
                  :format   => { :with => email_regex },
                  :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
```

That is currently how my validation looks like so I wanted to know how I could make it only accept .edu type email addresses.

Comment: instead of `[a-z]+` at the end, you would just put `edu`

Comment: If u want to accept emails from your college, than `@yourcollege.edu` will work as well.

Comment: @user482594: Unless the college has subdomains with their own email address (such as "prof@math.yourcollege.edu").

Comment: yeah my school has a subdomain of student before the yourcollege.edu part so I just added that in the regex and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact regex is:

```
email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@yourcollege\.edu\z/i
```

Like user482594 mentioned in the comments, just thought I would point out that you need the `\` before the `.`.

Comment: worked perfectly thanks a lot for the help, still a noob with all this so having such quick help with these problems makes it a lot easier.